# Python extract sting between apostrophes with regexp

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying in Python 2.7 to print a substring which is delimited by apostrophes in my original string:

```
a = "type.size(id='abc-66ttgg')"
```

I'd like to use a regex to save the substring `abc-66ttgg` in my variable b

Comment: Can you give an example of the full string, containing the substring?

Comment: This doesn't look like a full sample of code, given your question. Could you provide all of your code, along with how you want it to behave, so we can help you more effectively?

Comment: Thank you guys, I've added the right python syntax for my string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more information on the full string. But to get all the values within apostrophes using regex, I would do the following:

```
import re
b = re.findall(r"'(.+?)'", string)[0]
```

If you have a string like this:

```
string= string = "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 'sunt in culpa qui officia' deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

output:

```
'sunt in culpa qui officia'
```

Comment: It could help, depending on OP's data, to make sure that the opening`'` has a space preceding it, and the closing `'` has a space after it. This would help in examples like `string = "Excepteur didn't occaecat cupidatat non proident, 'sunt in culpa qui officia' deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."`. This would look like `re.findall(r"\s'(.+?)'\s", string)[0]`